# Django Models data storing

Tags: python, html, django

it's my first time working with Django models, I need help with my project.

I have created 1 model with only field experience, job type, salary.

Now I want another model which stores the table fields. Can anybody please help me?

Something like this website helps me:
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you could benefit from this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and have a look at [ask]. Your question is not very clear, particularly "_Now I want another model which stores the table fields_" does not make much sense and doesn't convey what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create another model and use ForeignKey like below :

```
class JobType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Employee(models.Model):
    job_type = models.ForeignKey(JobType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    experience = ...
    salary = ...
```

Comment: When I try to migrate I got error fields.E304

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of resources to learning about Django Model. Here is one of the official Documentation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/

If you have more specific question, please explain it clearly.

From your question,

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    experience = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    job_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    salary = models.IntegerField()

class AnotherTable(models.Model):
    data_1 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data_2 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    data_3 = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Comment: Please review the question again i have attached an image of example I an trying to make of.